# Dockerfile RUN --mount нет файла

Tags: docker, dockerfile

Такой вопрос, пытаюсь после остановки контейнера достать файл с отчетом export.json, при команде

```
docker run --rm --mount type=bind,source="$(pwd)"/out,target=/usr/local/bin/out test
```

Файл появляется в /out

Но хочу то же самое прописать в Dockerfile

```
FROM node

...

WORKDIR /usr/local/bin
COPY . .
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y chromium
RUN k6 version

CMD ["k6", "run", "-o", "experimental-prometheus-rw", Файл_сценария]
RUN --mount=type=bind,source=$PWD/out/,target=/usr/local/bin/out/,rw=true
```

Но файл не хочет появляется, в чем проблема?

Comment: Dockerfile - это просто инструкция по сборке образа, никаких mount в нём быть не может и в принципе не должно быть

Comment: хз пользовался https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#run---mount

Comment: А, ну там логика предполагается другая - получить доступ к вспомогательным файлам, необходимым для сборки. Вы же, как я понимаю, пытаетесь уже не собрать образ, а выполнить какую-то работу, не связанную со сборкой - вот лучше не надо так делать

Comment: Но ладно, если забить на здравый смысл, то как минимум меня смущает то, что вы в своём RUN не написали никакую команду для выполнения

Comment: теперь понял в чем проблема, спс